# Draw Tile images to one large Image for 2d Tile Map with swing

Tags: java, image, swing, dictionary, 2d

I am trying to draw a map for a 2D Tile game and I could use some help.  Here is the class that is supposed to draw the map.

```
`package view;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import model.*;

import javax.swing.*;
public class DrawMap extends JPanel{
    private static  Map map = Map.getMap(); 
    private static Tile[][] field = map.getField();
    BufferedImage im = new BufferedImage(3000,3000,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    public DrawMap() {
        init();


    }
    public void init(){
        Graphics g = im.getGraphics();
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < 100; j++){
                field[i][j].drawTile(g);
            }
        }
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(im,0,0,null);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("GameMap");
        DrawMap draw = new DrawMap();
        frame.add(draw);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
`
```

Essentially this makes a new Image that is going to be the map, then I go through my 2D array and call drawTile which is supposed to draw that tiles Image to the map Image I just created.  Here is what drawTile looks like.  I should not that img is a private BufferedImage that is not set to anything until I try to set it here in drawTile.

```
    'public void drawTile(Graphics g){
    try{
        img = ImageIO.read(new File("src/model/tileTest.png"));
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }
    g.drawImage(img, this.getXChord(), this.getYChord(), null);




}'
```

I am getting an Out of memory error from reading the image file.  If I make the drawMap class only search through the first 50 tiles I get an image but it is a bunch of really small tiles and 1 large image tile.  How should I be reading in the image so I don't get the out of memory error.  Id like to use buffered image if possible.  Also Im thinking I will need to use some kind of width and height parameters when I call g.drawImage in drawTile but I am not sure where to begin with that.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You're running this code for every tile:

```
public void drawTile(Graphics g){
    try {
        img = ImageIO.read(new File("src/model/tileTest.png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }
    g.drawImage(img, this.getXChord(), this.getYChord(), null);
}
```

That means you're rereading the image *for every tile*. For every tile you render, 60 times a second, you're running into your hard drive and grabbing that image. The images might be cached in memory, and thus it's running out of memory.

You definitely should be creating one image and using it multiple times. For example:

```
static Image img = null;

public Tile() {
    if (img == null) {
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(new File("src/model/tileTest.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
    }
}

public void drawTile(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(img, this.getXChord(), this.getYChord(), null);
}
```

As you get more and more tiles, you may want a more robut solution. But for now this should solve your problem.

(By the way, `e.printStackTrace(System.out)` is identical to `e.printStackTrace()` ;)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I am not getting the out of bounds error anymore.  My 2D array is 100 X 100 so I have a lot of tiles.  And eventually some tiles will use one picture and some a different picture i.e. different terrain items.  Right now my map will load, it takes a long time but its loading, however I get a very small square, like the whole map is in a inch by inch square, there may be 1 or 2 full sized tiles the rest just look like vertical lines, any ideas to fix that?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're saying, but I'm guessing it's due to the position you're rendering at, `this.getXChord()` and `this.getYChord()`. What do those methods return?

Comment: Yeah those methods return an integer value representing the tiles x and y coordinates respectively. Multiplying those numbers by say 10 or 30 seems to work now I have a decent looking map.  Still takes  along time to load though, any idea on how to speed it up?  Maybe I need to rethink how I make the 2D tile array?

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. You're saying the map takes time to load? But once it's loaded does it work well?

Comment: It might possibly just be swing...?

Comment: Yeah when I run the main in drawMap takes about 50 seconds before the window with the map pops up but when it does its all there I can live with that for now

Comment: Oh 50 seconds? There's something else going on... Try profiling your code. If you're using NetBeans, there's a built in profiler, otherwise use print statements and `System.currentTimeMillis()`. Is the image loading taking too long? Is it something else? Also, once the map is loaded, what's the FPS? If that's low, then it's a rendering problem. Otherwise, it's a loading problem.