# How to combine images in a JFrame?

Tags: java, image, swing, nested-loops, jlabel

I have been working on a project that is displaying a grid 16 x 16 of images, based on user interaction this grid follows the user on a dynamically larger base (an example would be a base that is 50 x 50) than the 16 x 16 display. 
However, I am using `JLabel` components to display these images, and every time the user interacts I have to move each of the 256 images and erase the ones that are no longer in the 16 x 16 display grid. This results in a lag that is close to a second per key press and is close to nonfunctional.

What I am looking to try to do is to chain these images together in the total width of the ground and simply move the focus to the portion that is within the 16 x 16 grid, making the process no longer have to use nested for loops for the display.

Is it possible that I could dynamically store and create these chained images for display using a label? If are there other ways to display .png files in Java that could be stored and used in a similar manner?

An example of my current methodology of having to draw every image upon every user interaction:

```
User user = game.user;

int floorWidth = game.floorWidth;
int floorHeight = game.floorHeight;

int pX = user.getTile().getX();
int pY = user.getTile().getY();

int minX = Math.max(pX - GameConstants.USER_DRAW_DISTANCE, 0);
int maxX = Math.min(floorWidth, pX + GameConstants.USER_DRAW_DISTANCE);

int minY = Math.max(pY - GameConstants.USER_DRAW_DISTANCE, 0);
int maxY = Math.min(floorHeight, pY + GameConstants.USER_DRAW_DISTANCE);
for (int i = minY; i < maxY; i++)
{
  for (int x = minX; x < maxX; x++)
  {
    Tile tile = floor.getTile(x, i);
    if (tile.getHasSeen())
    {
      JLabel cLabel = tile.imageLabel;
      cLabel.setLocation(340 + x * 32, 140 + i * 32);
      cLabel.setSize(64, 64);
      cLabel.setVisible(true);
      panel.add(cLabel, 1);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Avoid creating and adding new JLabels and instead simply change the image icons present in the current JLabels. If you are constantly reading in image files, avoid doing this and instead, if possible, read your images into image icons once and save. For more help, consider creating and posting a [mre] program with your question.

Comment: I get the impression that `JScrollPane` would be appropriate here. Create one large `JPanel` and place all your `JLabel`s on it. Then make that `JPanel` the scrollable client of the `JScrollPane` and set the preferred size of the `JScrollPane` big enough to display your 16x16 grid.

Comment: In addition to use a JScrollPane for scrolling, you would use a JPanel with a `GridLayout`, You can configure the grid to automatically wrap at 16 images. Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html). Don't attempt to set the size/location of your components. It is the job of the layout manager to set the size/location. Another option is to use a JList and add ImageIcons to the list. The list can also be configured to wrap. The tutorial also has a section on `How to Use Lists`.

Comment: An alternative would be to use your images as tiles.  Here's one example.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30004538/draw-tile-images-to-one-large-image-for-2d-tile-map-with-swing

Answer (score 1):

In principle your idea should work. So you're probably doing something else wrong.

I've made an example, where it displays a 16x16 square of JLabels out of 256x256 JLabels. When you move the mouse over the panel, it changes the layout to show a new set of 16x16 JLabels. The change is pretty snappy, definitely not a 1 second delay.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

public class GridViewer{
    int x0, y0;
    int N = 256;
    int display = 16;
    int length = 32;
    List<JLabel> showing = new ArrayList<>();
    List<JLabel> available = new ArrayList<>();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(){
        Dimension sz = new Dimension(length*display, length*display);
        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
            return sz;
        }
    };
    public void showGui(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        panel.setLayout(null);

        panel.addMouseMotionListener( new MouseAdapter(){
            Random r = new Random();
            @Override
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent evt){
                int x = evt.getX();
                int y = evt.getY();
                //map to position on the image to the position on the grid.
                x0 = x/2;
                x0 = Math.min(x0, N-display);

                y0 = y/2;
                y0 = Math.min(y0, N-display);
                updateLayout();
            }
        });

        for(int i = 0; i<N*N; i++){
            available.add(createItem(i));
        }

        updateLayout();

        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    /**
     * Creates a solid color jlabel, could be used to load an image
     * as an icon.
     **/
    JLabel createItem(int i){
        JLabel l = new JLabel("");
        int r = (i/256);
        int g = (0)&255;
        int b = (i%256);
        int c = (r << 16 ) + ( g << 8 ) + b;
        l.setBackground(new Color(c));
        l.setOpaque(true);
        l.setSize(length, length);

        return l;
    }
    public void updateLayout(){
        for(JLabel l: showing){
            panel.remove(l);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i<display; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j<display; j++){
                JLabel l = available.get((i + x0) + (j+y0)*N);
                panel.add(l);
                l.setLocation( i*length, j*length);
                showing.add(l);
            }
        }        
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        EventQueue.invokeLater( () -> new GridViewer().showGui() );

    }
}
```

Some variations.

**Use a GridLayout**

Using a layout manager has a lot of advantages. Especially when it comes to using different displays, fonts and platforms? When adding and removing elements, it could make partially showing elements tough.

**Use a large JPanel with a ScrollPane**

We could create a single JPanel and add all 256x256 components to it, then use a scroll pane to set the view. This would have an advantage of completely separating the layout and the view. Somebody wants a larger window, you don't have to change the layout, the view gets bigger and you just see more of the layout. For 256x256 components, it should perform well but if you have too many components you might want to reconsider it.

**Use a JPanel and override paintComponent**

This would involve loading your 'png' files as awt `Image`s (probably `BufferedImage`s) and drawing them with the graphics object. You would need to handle all of the layout and rendering. It gives you quite a bit of power over how you want to render your components.